# how to disable htaccess 404 redirection?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a website that is built in PHP, i am using HTACCESS file to hide the .PHP extention from the users, Now im trying to builg a blog in www.sitename.com/blog, i have created the folder and uploaded the files there. The problem is that when i try to access /blog it redirects me to 404. is there anyway to fix this?

my HTACCESS content is

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

    #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type:s
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.vartag\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://vartag.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Rewrite condition only checks for file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

"blog" is a directory, so this won't match and apache will try to open "blog.php", which doesn't exist.

Change this line to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will check for directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for existence for `.php` file before adding `.php` in the request URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(vartag\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```